# It appears Firefox adds 3px to the top of most elements, compared to IE9

Tags: html, css, firefox, cross-browser

Yet another "Firefox does not agree with IE9" and the other way around problem.

I could explain what is going on, but an image says more than a thousand words, so I took a screenie of FF and IE:

[image: This sucks]

Here is the markup:

```
<div align="center" id="cmContainer" style="background-color: #8CFE70; border: 1px solid #2D9500; border-radius: 4px; width: 400px; height: 161px;"> 
   <span style="color: #2C2C2C; font-family: Arial; font-size: 20px; text-align: center;" /> 
   <font size="24">Look!</font>
   <br>
   See how different IE renders from FF?
   <br>
   How can I fix this?
   </span>
   <br>
   <input value="CODE" type="text" size="20" style="font: 20px Arial; color: #000000; background-color: #F3F3F3; border: 1px solid #8D8D8D; width: 300px; border-radius: 2px; text-align: center; margin-top: 0px; padding: 5px 3px 5px 3px; " />
   <br>
   <input type="button" value="I'm a button!" />
</div>
```

What can be causing it? I have tried several different stuff with Firebug, but to no avail.

Why does web development have to be this annoying? :)

P.S:**Before** commenting about my use of Inline Styles, please note that it is how my project requires it. :)

EDIT: By using a CSS Reset, as suggested by Cygal and Christophe, and by applying it only on my objects, here is the result:

[image]

Cant really ask for anything better, as easwee so nicely pointed out. ;)

Comment: Don't have the time to test it on both right now, but did you try and set the padding for the div? Maybe one of the two browsers adds his own "standard" if it's not defined

Comment: Does anything change if it's minified?

Comment: Have you tried using Firebug (in Firefox) and the developer tools (in IE9) to understand the layout in a bit more depth?

Comment: @Semyazas - I tried with padding: 0px; however that changed nothing. as you see in the image, it gets worse the longer down you go

Comment: @Richard - I am using Firebug, yes.

Comment: @Preacher - How could I minify this?

Comment: You may want to add an alternative for Arial there... Arial is Microsoft-owned so not commonly available on Macs or other systems.

Comment: Just remove all the new lines (for testing only), so your code is all on one line with no whitespace between tags.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## The issue

There is no specification regarding the default margin, padding, border and font-size of default elements. Here, it appears that the margin of your title is bigger in Firefox than in IE9. Note that every solution that only fixes this specific problem will *not* prevent it from appearing in other places.

## The solution

- Reset CSS: if you do want to have exactly the same rendering, you can use a technique called "reset CSS" which sets everything to zero everywhere it makes sense. It is then up to you to choose the values you want. You could try the [Eric Meyers's reset CSS](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/) or [other ones](http://www.cssreset.com/).
- Base stylesheet: reseting the CSS could and will have unexpected effects on your style: the effects could be surprising and there is a reason why the browser have default values for elements. If you only want to correct "know incompatibility issues", then you can use a [simple base stylesheet](http://covertprestige.info/css/base/) (this one exists in both compact and full modes).

However, remember that it's OK if every website doesn't appear the same on every browser, and that it *won't* appear the same anyway due to issues you can't control (mainly due the size of the fonts chosen by users and old browsers). Another solution would then be to let go and use techniques like sizes in em. (and not in piexels) when appropriate. :)

Comment: +1 Nicely explained. And I really think that a person has no right to be a perfectionist and demand a pixel-perfect design while he is using a markup that dates back to WW1.

Comment: By using a Reset CSS, it was near pixel perfect. @easwee - I certainly don't hope you are referring to me, Sir. ;)

Answer (score 7):

I think it comes from border that firefox doesn't count in the global height of the element in opposition to IE that integrate borders in elem height...

So, the difference should be 3px between them because the last border-bottom does not affect the rest.

**Edit**

Have you tried to use a CSS reset like : http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

Comment: The CSS reset worked, the layout looks the same on both browser! (not that it looks particularly pretty, but thats where I come in :P )

Answer (score 0):

Try specifying the margin on the body tag, that should allow you specify exactly how much of a margin you want on the body of the page for all browsers

```
<body style="margin: 0px">
```

Answer (score 0):

- What kind of system **requires** inline styles? Does it "require" `font` elements, too? (BTW, there is no such size as "24". Valid values are 1 to 6.).
- Why would any user care if rendering is off by a few pixels in one browser? It's not like they would actually compare it and then dismiss the site because of it.
- Your first `span` tag is XHTML self-closed (`<span ... />`). Not only doesn't IE support that, it's simply wrong in this case.
- Is the document in standards mode?

Comment: **Mine** does - all the content is dynamically generated with my Windows app, and the code is for previewing the design. Also, thanks for notifying me about the /> in the Span tag - didnt see that :)

Comment: Yes, there is a metatag present, specifying IE9 standards mode

Answer (score 0):

```
-moz-box-sizing:border-box
```

Should solve your problem altough your html is brutal.

```
<div align="center" id="cmContainer" style="background-color: #8CFE70; border: 1px solid #2D9500; border-radius: 4px; width: 400px;-moz-box-sizing:border-box;"> 
   <span style="color: #2C2C2C; font-family: Arial; font-size: 20px; text-align: center;"> 
   <font size="24">Look!</font>
   <br>
   See how different IE renders from FF?
   <br>
   How can I fix this?
   </span>
   <br>
   <input value="CODE" type="text" size="20" style="font: 20px Arial; color: #000000; background-color: #F3F3F3; border: 1px solid #8D8D8D; width: 300px; border-radius: 2px; text-align: center; margin-top: 0px; padding: 5px 3px 5px 3px; " />
   <br>
   <input type="button" value="I'm a button!" />
</div>
```

Comment: Nope, it did not solve it. I know the HTML sucks, however it is just for previewing within my Windows app